# YouTube at double speed on mobile

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube

How do I listen to YouTube videos at double-speed?

On the desktop I'm able to change the playback speed to 1.5x or 2x. With podcasts, I'm able to listen to them on my iPhone at 1.5x or 2x speed. Shouldn't  I be able to watch YouTube videos at double speed on the iOS app?

Comment: Chloe, you should check my answer because, opposed to the correct answer, it doesn't require leaving the browser (which I think it rocks)

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru Are you referring to my answer? It doesn't require leaving the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can now be done with the latest version of [Youtube Mobile App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/youtube-watch-videos-music-and-live-streams/id544007664?mt=8)

"What's New in Version 12.33

**• Adjust video playback speed with new player controls**"

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's sad to know this took them, what, five years to implement? Still, I'd rather use a proper app that lets me shut off the screen and save battery.

Answer (score 12):

#### Updated answer for those who still prefer to watch in Safari

In the iOS Shortcuts app you can find a shortcut that will change the speed of any video it finds on the web page you're on when you run it. You run it from the share sheet in Safari.

Activate it in the Shortcuts app in Gallery → Javascript Shortcuts → Change video speed.

Visit a Youtube video in Safari and use the share sheet to run the newly added shortcut. It will ask you what speed to play the video at.

---

#### Original answer

1. On the video's mobile Youtube page, tap the menu button at the top left (or right). Scroll to the bottom and switch
   to Desktop view.*

[image: Youtube desktop version]

2. Change the speed controls just like you would on your computer.
3. Play the video by tapping it and it will use the new speed settings.

*If you're in YouTube desktop mode but **still don't see the gear icon** then tap Safari's action/share button and request desktop version from there as well. The *request desktop* icon looks like a monitor/iMac.

[image: Icon to request desktop version]

(I recently learned that you can also tap and hold Safari's refresh button to request the desktop version of a page)

If you lock the screen Safari will pause playback, but it can be resumed either from the lock screen or your headset to allow audio only.

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru You have been repeating that same promotion of your app several times in this question, and indeed even in the comment section for this answer. You have also repeatedly claimed that this answer "doesn't work" on TED, etc. My answer now—just like before—is: this answer is not meant to work on other sites. Reread the question that was asked.

Comment: You are right. I forgot about it only working for Youtube (I didn't remember the question when I added my last comment). I am sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I've released a new app made just for this: [Speedeo](http://www.speedeoapp.com)

You can watch any YouTube videos on it at up to 2x the speed. Great for tutorials, presentations, and just saving time in general.

Note: I'm one of the authors of the app. If you have any feedback please let me know!

Comment: You also happen to have made it...

Comment: Did you also post the original question? This seems spammy to me.

Comment: ? No... I have no affiliation with Chloe. I'm just the maker of the app

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you for making this - you've significantly improved my quality of life.

It'd be nice if you integrated with the sharing widgets in iOS so I could open YouTube links directly in your app instead of copying the link and pasting it in. I'd also love to go faster than 2x (I routinely get up to ~3.5x with [Video Speed Controller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk)).

Comment: @cgenco Thanks for the support and feedback! I'll let my team know about upping the maximum speed, although anything above 2.5x usually causes videos to become skippy. We will definitely be looking into the sharing widgets so stay tuned!

Comment: Thanks for self-disclosing - that's all we ask is to let people know you have a connection with a product. +1 in my book - there's no time limit on adding a useful or new answer to any post. Thanks everyone for the clarifying comments

Comment: This looks like nice app. A killer feature to add would be 10 Sec skip forward/backward like in Amazon's video player.

Comment: I searched for 'Youtube speed' on App Store, could not find your app. Idea to have this sorted out for better SEO, good luck!

Comment: @WimdenHerder thanks for the advice! look up "speedeo" if you can't find the app

Comment: This solution implies opening another app to change the speed. Playbex (posted below) can change the speed without leaving Safari.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, mobile versions often have much **less** functionality. With the official YouTube app there is (currently) no function to speed up a video.

There might be an external app containing this feature, but by default there is no functionality for this.

Answer (score 2):

**This app seems not to be available in the Store anymore**

[The Swift Player app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/swift-player-speed-up-video/id545216639?mt=8) should be able to accomplish what you need, but it is $3.99, so that might not be an option.

Comment: Surprisingly, my iTunes shows a popup saying "The item you've requested is not currently available in the U.S. store".

Answer (score 2):

**This app seems not to be available in the Store anymore**

I'm very happy with [Play Tube Free from VietMobile](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/play-tube-free-player-for/id552248120?mt=8). It's one of the best because it has:

- playback speed control
- swipe gestures to jump forward/backward
- video quality lock

I always use all three to watch tutorials and such.

Comment: My iTunes shows a popup saying "The item you've requested is not currently available in the U.S. store", so I can't get it either.

Answer (score 2):

I HAVE THE ANSWER ;)

Uninstall youtube app if you have it.

Go to App Store -> download "[chrome](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-chrome/id535886823?mt=8)".

Open it and go to youtube.com.

On the top right there are three dots -> request desktop site

If you play the video you should be able to see the gear on the bottom right of the video player!

Thank me later.

Comment: Wow, YouTube is 48MB, but Chrome is 69MB!

Comment: I found that you do not need to uninstall YouTube. You can ignore the prompt to open in YouTube, or change the setting in Chrome to *not* use YouTube. You also have to click the ... twice to request the desktop site, once in the YouTube page, and again in the Chrome app. They both have the '...'. If you only request desktop site in one of them, then it just changes the layout but the video widget is the standard Apple one with no controls. I also found that it *remembers* the 2x speed, so that's good!

Comment: The downside is that you can't watch the video fullscreen because it's "not supported". It's too bad youtube doesn't just add this feature to their app.

Answer (score 2):

I made an action extension for iOS Safari that does just that. For those unaware, action extension basically adds button to Safari action sheet that allows you to adjust video playback speed. Works on both iPhone and iPad. It works with YouTube and virtually any other HTML5 video player, in Safari itself, rather then having to open different app. https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1205188880

Comment: I wish they'd make extensions like these more visible somehow. I've never once gone on the AppStore with the thought of looking for, basically, a new button for the system's share action sheet. There's not even a separate category for it. AppStore ironically is a sad excuse for an app.

Answer (score 1):

[Tubex](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tubex-videos-music-for-youtube/id939906112?mt=8) is a free (ad-supported) iOS app that offers a range of playback speeds and picture-in-picture support, in addition to all the usual YouTube functionality.

Comment: I just used this app. Jan 2017

Comment: This app seems to have been taken off the App Store

Answer (score 0):

You can install **[MyTube](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mytube-best-tube-music-video-play-for-youtube/id964383263?mt=8)** from the app store which is **free** (non-paid).

During playback, click the box containing the number 1 and set your desired speed such as 1.5 or 2.0. Intermediate speeds such as 1.25 are unfortunately not available.

The app is **ad supported**, so you might get a couple of ads as you interact with the app.

Answer (score -2):

Just install the Puffin browser and enjoy..

Answer (score -3):

Just download SpeedTube on the app store

Comment: You don't answer with bla bla bla in an answer. That's really arrogant and immature.